# Algorithm for partitioning graph edges into n-cycles (small number of vertices, say 60)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, coloring

So we have a graph with a small number of vertices (can be limited to as little as 20 if making this algorithm is hard). Lots of edges though, it is probably a 2 or at most 8 partite graph.

I'm looking for an algorithm that will take the edges of such a graph and split them up into cycles all of some specified size n. And by split them up I mean return a set of disjoint sets of edges, with every edge from the original graph in one of the returned sets.

This is for educational purposes (it's to help tell a story about Maryam Mirzakhani solving the problem of generating tripartite graphs that can be split into 5-cycles http://sharif.edu/~emahmood/papers/MR1366852English.pdf )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but Partitioning a Tripartite graph into Triangles (PTT) is NP-Hard, that is, there is no polynomial time algorithm capable of solving this problem unless P=NP. It seems that your problem is a generalization of PTT...

Hope this can help you. 
Let me know if this is not what you're looking for...